# What is a Wombo Combo?

Tags: league-of-legends, terminology

I'd like to know what exactly the term '*Wombo Combo*' means.

Does it mean something such as using all 5 champion's ultimates at the same time?

Is it a term only used in League of Legends?

---

**Edit**

So according to [this site](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/wombo-combo) the origin of the '*Wombo Combo*'  term comes from Super Smash Bros Melee (amazing game too) to define an "crazy combo".

For LoL does it means instakill everyone?

What are the famous '*Wombo Combo*' of LoL?

Comment: Relevant: http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/wombo-combo

Comment: I believe an example of that is Leona and Graves, as champions with good spell combinations.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The origin of the "Wombo Combo" comes from Super Smash Bros Melee, as you stated in the question, and it is defined as *two players in the game chain together certain moves to highly damage and/or kill the enemy*.  The moves compliment each other and thus create a combo.
In League of Legends it means the same, to combine moves (not necessarily a champions ultimate only) to create a very strong "combo" attack with your teammate(s).

> **What are the famous Wombo Combo of LoL?**

They are ever changing and new ones being made, but some examples are:

- [Blitzcrank's](http://gameinfo.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/blitzcrank/) **Power Fist** to knock someone up, followed by [Yasuo's](http://gameinfo.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/yasuo/) **Last Breath** to deal the damage.
- [Orianna's](http://gameinfo.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/orianna/) **Command: Shockwave** to bring everyone together then [Jarvan IV's](http://gameinfo.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/jarvaniv/) **Cataclysm** to keep them there.

Comment: This answer makes the most sense, as it relates to the origin of the term, rather than what ktash said above "I think this means this because I thought it was like that"

Comment: Shockwave to pull them together, cataclysm to hold them there, bullet time and kennen ultimate over the top of it, thresh box just as catacylsm is ending...that's an example of an ultimate wombo combo. If you can pull off that sort of synergy it will just destroy the entire enemy team if you manage to land it.

Comment: @Tim B you forgot about wukong ultimate!

Comment: @Pierre Only in hexakill, I already used 5 :p but yes Wukong would be another option that could take the place of Kenen or j4 in the combo.

Comment: Or Orianna's ultimate followed by malphite ultimate followed by yasuo ultimate.

Answer (score 3):

[Wombo Combo](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/wombo-combo) is a term used, primarily, to mean the complete and utter destruction of another person or team, especially if it is done quickly. It is originally from a video of a Super Smash Bros Melee match (below), but has since grown in popularity and is used for many different games and situations to the same effect. There are a large number of Youtube videos that use the same audio track and overlay other situations, gaming or not, as a parody of the original video.

Usually when used in games these days, it is done so in celebration or as a taunt or bragging to the other team. Most of the time, it is just meant as trash talk and is not referring to any action in particular as a Wombo Combo.

Potentially related, it is also a [Pizza Combination at Round Table Pizza](http://www.roundtablepizza.com/rtp/menu.asp?ftype=specialty) with "Primo pepperoni, Italian sausage, linguica, bacon, mushrooms, tomatoes, artichoke hearts, green onions on zesty red sauce."

Comment: Wombo Combo isn't about destroying another team, its specifically the knocking back and forth of an enemy player while keeping them stunned like in the video. For example, alistair knocks a player away, blitz pulls them back, and then alistair knocks them up, and then blitz knocks them up. Thats the kind of play that would be typically referred to as a wombo combo

Comment: @Lawton yes, that's how the original description of it is. However, it isn't always used that way, especially not recently, at least in my experience. In every experience I've had with people saying Wombo Combo to me, it has always been a taunt or bragging, and usually had nothing to do with any stun-locking or back-and-forth attacks. That's what the answer is based off of. Also, the definitions on sites like Urban Dictionary don't really mention the stun-locking requirement either.

Comment: @Ktash So you're basing the definition of the Wombo Combo based on your own personal experience? Answer definitely sounds way too opinionated to be a real answer.